# Listbox tooltips issue in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

After searching on the web, I add the the tooltips for the listbox in my asp.net site as

```
            var lst = GetData(); // getting dictionary list
            listbox.DataSource = lst;
            listbox.DataTextField = "key";
            listbox.DataValueField = "value";
            listbox.DataBind();

            foreach (ListItem item in listbox.Items)
            {
                item.Attributes["title"] = item.Text;
            }
```

but it is not showing tooltips correctly. So when I try to view the source
it's shown as

```
<select name="listbox" >
<option value="tooltips here">
```

So I use developer tools to change value of the option to title, it shows the tooltips correctly.

Why title attributes change to value attribute ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue just now after reading this [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1244253.aspx?Title%20Attribute%20Problem).
The answer says that **title attribute is lost on every postback**. No idea why it is lost.
So I put

```
foreach (ListItem item in listbox.Items)
{
     item.Attributes["title"] = item.Text;
}
```

outside the `if(!isPostBack)` and it solves my issue.

Comment: You should mark this as your answer so everyone will know that this solved the problem.

Comment: Okay I will. It says I can only accept my own answer tomorrow. Thanks for the tip. :)